# Collision between player and ball with sprites in Pygame

Tags: python, pygame

We are trying to programm a collision between players and a ball in a HeadSoccer-like game. If the player stands I would like the ball to just bounce off. If the player moves we would like to have a new direction of the ball after collision.

Our code looks like this:

```
def collision(self):
        normalenvektor = pygame.Vector2(0,1)
        speed = self.speed.length()
        if self.rect.colliderect(player_1):
            x1 = self.x - player_1.x
            y1 = self.y - player_1.y

            verbindungsvektor1 = pygame.Vector2(x1,y1)
            
            angle_to_p1 = normalenvektor.angle_to(verbindungsvektor1)
            if angle_to_p1 >= 45 and angle_to_p1 < 135:
                self.speed[0] *= -1
                self.rect.x += abs(self.rect.left-player_1.rect.right)
                if player_1.speed != pygame.Vector2(0,0):
                    self.speed = speed*(player_1.speed.normalize() + self.speed.normalize())
            elif angle_to_p1 >= 135 and angle_to_p1 < 225:
                self.speed[1] *= -1
                self.rect.y += abs(self.rect.bottom-player_1.rect.top)
                if player_1.speed != pygame.Vector2(0,0):
                    self.speed = speed*(player_1.speed.normalize() + self.speed.normalize())
            elif angle_to_p1 >= 225 and angle_to_p1 < 315:
                self.speed[0] *= -1
                self.rect.x = abs(self.rect.right-player_1.rect.left)
                if player_1.speed != (0,0):
                    self.speed = speed*(player_1.speed.normalize() + self.speed.normalize())
            elif player_1.rect.bottom < 7*width/8:
                self.speed[1] *= -1                          
        
        elif self.rect.colliderect(player_2):
            x2 = self.x - player_2.x
            y2 = self.y - player_2.y

            verbindungsvektor2 = pygame.Vector2(x2,y2)

            angle_to_p2 = normalenvektor.angle_to(verbindungsvektor2)
            if angle_to_p2 >= 45 and angle_to_p2 < 135:
                self.speed[0] *= -1
            elif angle_to_p2 >= 135 and angle_to_p2 < 225:
                self.speed[1] *= -1
            elif angle_to_p2 >= 225 and angle_to_p2 < 315:
                self.speed[0] *= -1
            elif player_2.rect.bottom < 7*width/8:
                self.speed[1] *= -1

    # Anzeigen der Vektoren
```

Why doesn't it work?

Comment: Could you provide some more context, such as the expected behavior of the code, as well as the actual behavior?